# Inserting from one database table to another

Tags: java, mysql, spring, netezza

I have data in a mySQL database table. I am selecting this data and trying to insert it to a Netezza database table. I am using the spring framework and have a entity class called Student.

Some of the fields in the mySQL database table are in Integer format but the equivalent field in Netezza is in character format.

I am using a JDBC template and getting the data from mySQL and inserting that Student object to Netezza.

Here is my method:

```
 String sqlStudent="INSERT INTO STUDENT(STUDENTID,CLASSID,COURSEID,TESTDATE,SCOREDATE) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?)";
 netezzaJDBCTemplate.update(sqlStudent,new Object[] {student.getStudentId(),student.getClassId(),student.getCourseId(),student.getTestDate(),student.getScoreDate)});
```

I get an error when I do this. I even tried hard coding the INSERT.

```
 Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.jdbc.BadSqlGrammarException: PreparedStatementCallback; bad SQL grammar [INSERT INTO STUDENT(STUDENTID,CLASSID,COURSEID,TESTDATE,SCOREDATE) VALUES (1521995,134,21,'2014-02-15 00:00:00','2014-02-15 00:00:00') )]; nested exception is org.netezza.error.NzSQLException: Parameter Index out of range: 1
```

Is this because of the difference in the column data types between the 2 databases? or am I missing something else?

Please help.

Comment: Why `new studentMapper()`. JdbcTemplate's update method wont accept `RowMapper` correct ? You using any custom implementation?

Comment: Good catch! So I hard coded INSERT Statement with values, but still get an error - nested exception is org.netezza.error.NzSQLException: Parameter Index out of range: 1

Comment: It seems somewhere you are setting `preparedStmt.setXXX(1,xxxx)` and you don't have any `?` in the current statement. Post your full stack trace, it might help.

Comment: @Rp- I think that was the issue (having the RowMapper in the update). Can you add that as an answer so I can choose it as an answer?

Comment: **Netezza is designed for bulk loads**. Please don't do Row-By-Row inserts, your DBA will have fits when he finds out. The perfomance will be **dreadfully** slow! Use an ETL tool, or generate a flat file that you then load in batch, or write batches of data into a unix named pipe that the Netezza bulk loader then reads from.

Comment: @NWest thanks for the suggestion. I cannot use an ETL but will try to investigate how I can do do bulk insert using spring batch framework.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`new studentMapper()` might be the issue. JdbcTemplate's update method wont accept RowMapper correct?

If your are not using `NamedParameterJdbcTemplate` try to prefer that over regular `JdbcTemplate` which lets you bind the sql params with names.